# C# convert a number into words

Tags: c#, int, void

I have this private void here

```
private void NumbersToWords(int number)
    {
        string word;
        if (number == 8)
        {
            word = "Eight";
        }
        return word;
    }
```

And I am calling it in another private void

```
lblDaysToGo.Text = NumbersToWords(info.DaysToGo.ToString());
```

But I am getting this error....What am I doing wrong?

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'
```

Comment: `private void NumbersToWords(int number)` come on now..you need to change the void to `string` `private string NumbersToWords(int number)`

Comment: And after you fix the method to return `string` you'll need to fix the place you are calling it to pass an `int` instead of a `string`

Comment: this is basic programming concept I would suggest some remedial reading [MSDN C# Void](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: A method that is a void does not return any value.  So you returning the value of `word` is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method to

```
private string NumbersToWords(int number)
{
    string word = "";
    if (number == 8)
    {
        word = "Eight";
    }
    return word;
}
```

Previously you did not return a value, indicated by `void`.

Comment: Hey so now I am getting a new error `Use of unassigned local variable 'word'`

Comment: I copied the code and forgot to change it. BTW I added a change

Comment: I didn't downvote it, i upvoted it and it will be checked as correct :)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to return a `string`, from a `void` function. You need to change your function to be:

```
private string NumbersToWords(int number)
```

Once you cover that, you'll need to change:

```
lblDaysToGo.Text = NumbersToWords(info.DaysToGo.ToString());
```

You're passing in a `string` when you should be passing in an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very descriptive - the only place you can use `void` as a type is the return type of a method, so that's the first place to look.

The return type of your function is `void`. You are trying to return a `string` from it.

Change the return type to `string`:

```
private string NumbersToWords(int number)
```